# Implementing Observer Design Pattern to change button color?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I'm trying to change the color of the button but I need to use the ODP. Here is what I have so far:

```
if(mousePosition.x > 50 && mousePosition.y > 50 && mousePosition.x < 125 && mousePosition.y < 100)
{
    //When statement is true it will create an event
    HoverEvent hoverObject = new HoverEvent(this, "hover");
    DispatchEvent(hoverObject); //Passing the event to the dispatcher
}
```

Then in another class I have this:

```
public class EventDispatcher implements IEventDispatcher{

//inserts a new event listener to that observers list which is indexed by the event type.
@Override
public void AddListener(String stEventType, IEventListener el) {
    if(stEventType.equals("hover"))
    {
        el.notify();
    }
    return;
}

//removes an event listener from that observers list which is indexed by the event type.
@Override
public void RemoveListener(String stEventType, IEventListener el) {
    return;
}

//When an event occurs, get the type of event and notify all subcribers.
@Override
public void DispatchEvent(IEvent e) {
    String x = e.StEventType();//Checking the type of event
    //Now what?!?!?
    return;
}
```

Now that I am in the DispatchEvent I don't know how to change the color of the box. I thought I should create another class to change the color (which you can see here):

```
public class ChangeColor implements IEventListener {

@Override
public void notify(IEvent e) {

}
```

How do I connect that DispatchEvent method to the change color class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observer pattern implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003931/observer-pattern-implementation)
While the question is about c++, the following answer is pseudo-java and should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8003980/3802841